# Setting blank text in c# combo box

Tags: c#, combobox

So I am using a combo box that the user is only allowed to choose a few options. I am working on user validation right now. When you start the program the there is no text in the combo box. I want to be able to reset the combo box back to that default and make it blank when ever I need to. I have been trying things such as`comboBox1.Text = "";` and that was a no go. I even tried doing `comboBox1.Items.Clear();` Then re adding all the items back in again. Re adding the items wouldn't be an issue except one of the combo boxes is very lengthy.

Is there a way to make a combo box returns to its default of being blank?

Comment: If the user is not allowed to type in the combobox (DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList) then setting the SelectedIndex to -1 should clear the combobox selection. What is the DropDownStyle property value?

Answer (score 2):

use :

```
ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1
```

Comment: That was a lot easier than I expected. Friend ended up doing a massive chain of If logic to do one line of code *sigh*

Comment: Please, mark the answer if is it correct, Thank you!